# PDF Export: Color Profile Conversion (Affinity Designer)

Tags: pdf, color-conversion, affinity-designer

I am new to AD and using the current version as trial. I worked for 10 years with Illustrator but would like to switch.

I need to export a PDF/X-3:2002, but it seems there is only X-1a and X-3:2003. Right?

X-3:2003 doesn't converts my bitmaps to CMYK, it remains in the PDF as sRGB.
X-1a:2003 does convert my bitmaps to CMYK, but it also converts embedded PDF files (both vectors, a QR code and the logo) to rasterized images.

**What I want is convert everything to CMYK, but keep vectors as vectors**. It was plain easy with Illustrator, but AD seems to lack a lot of PDF export features.